# Will self retain within block?

Tags: objective-c, ios, block, retain, self

Before/After call the block, the retaincount is always 1. 
From [apple block doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW1) we know that the self should retain. Can anyone know why?

```
NSLog(@"Before block retain count: %d", [self retainCount]);    
void (^block)(void) = ^(void){
    UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hometown.png"];
    [self setImage:img];
    NSLog(@"After block retain count: %d", [self retainCount]);
};
block();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, **retainCount is useless.  Don't call it.**.

Blocks only retain captured objects when the block is copied.  Thus, `self` won't be retained by the block in that example.

Comment: In the doc it just said:
In a reference-counted environment, by default when you reference an Objective-C object within a block, it is retained. This is true even if you simply reference an instance variable of the object. Object variables marked with the __block storage type modifier, however, are not retained.

The apple doc really confused me a lot. Thank bbum.

Comment: Please file a bug on the docs, then.  I agree-- it isn't entirely clear.  It should be more explicit that the retain *may* only occur when the block is copied and the language surrounding instance variables is a bit off, too.

Answer (score 0):

OK I did some research, now things became more clear. firstly, I didn't use @property on block1, which means when I set it, nothing is copied, so they are not retained, secondly, if we do a [block copy]， the variables will be retained, if we dont copy, the block points to a stack address, copy it to heap to make it safe.

the variable 'array' is a Member variable, so it's not retained and meanwhile the self will be retained, whether you put it in the block or not, if the variable is a local variable, it will be retained. ( this is the thing that Im still confused abt, why the member variable is not retained,instead the self is added one more on retain count??? pls answer me?)

after using the block we could set it to nil self.block = nil; to make variables released, and avoid the retain cycle.

PS. a method to break retain cycle is use __block id weakSelf = self; in the block, so it means __block variables are also not retained.